# Excel Summary sheet multiple worksheets with drop downs

Tags: excel

[SUMMARY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTdBm.jpg) [SHEETS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPzZP.jpg) [CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl9rH.jpg)I am trying to create a project tracker with a summary page. Each team member has their own worksheet to track projects and I need a summary of all of their data.
Columns 'Rep', 'Project Type', 'Task' and 'Status' all have drop down menus.
'Task' column allows you to pick multiple tasks and then have a status for each.

I tried using formulas and a VBA code but none are working (my first try at code)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So to understand that right, the idea is to copy the current values of the 5 columns from each individual sheet and fill them in a seperate sheet one line for each team member?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and how the result was unacceptable.

Comment: To clarify: I want a summary sheet that shows the staus of each team members projects. The 5 columns/rows from the individual sheets would be copied to a summary but would also be tracked by the person's name (name of the worksheet). I'll add a picture of the code I tried, which does exactly nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a situation where "... each xxx has its own sheet ..." combined with the challenge to report across all sheet, the objective is to generate ONE data source from the many sheets.

Doing this with VBA is possible, but not an easy job, especially not for beginners.

Doing this with Power Query (Get & Transform) will be a lot easier. There are lots of free online tutorials and resources for Power Query and how to consolidate data from multiple Excel worksheets into one query.

Start by looking into that. It's bigger than what fits into an answer here, but that's what you'll need to do.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've never heard of Power Query; looking into it now.